# Scroll on container changes speed on scrolling larger groing containers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

It is possible to improve scrolling on a list with large number of containing objects.

```
<ul>
  <li>text1</li>
  <li>text2</li>
  <li>text3</li>
  <li>text4</li>
  <li>...</li>
  .
  .
  .
  <li>text1000</li>
</ul>
```

Whenever I scroll over 90% of the elements in container, I make a js call that will load more results to my container and will add my rest of the elements to the ul.

Can I modify the scroll speed when scrolling based on the number of the results?

p.s. I don't have any code that I have tried on this situation. I don't know how to do this. This is the last attempt in order to solve a problem that I have.
p.s. 2 i would like a solution without any extra library than jquery or jqm.

**Edit:
By *modify the scroll speed*  I mean to change the scroll to go faster if there are many objects and slower otherwise**

Comment: What does it mean _"modify the scroll speed"_?

Comment: even facebook has that problem.

Comment: I think slowing or speeding up the scrolling would be frustrating to users... just my thoughts on that.

Comment: Yes, but this is my request :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this kind of snippet:

{Change timeout delay for less boring effect using scrollbar}

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3KSwv/)

```
(function () {
    var $ul = $('ul');
    for (var i = 1; i < 1001; i++)
    $ul.append('<li>test::' + i + '</li>');

    var lastScrollTop = 0,
        st,
        direction;

    function getDirection() {
        st = window.pageYOffset;
        if (st > lastScrollTop) {
            direction = "down";
        } else {
            direction = "up";
        }
        lastScrollTop = st;
        return direction;
    }


    var scrolling = function () {
        var $window = $(this);
        $window.off('scroll');
        var delta = $ul.height() / 10,
            scroll = $window.scrollTop();
        if (getDirection() === "down") $window.scrollTop(delta + scroll);
        else $window.scrollTop(scroll - delta);
        console.log($(window).scrollTop());
        lastScrollTop = this.pageYOffset;
        setTimeout(function () {
            $window.on('scroll', scrolling);
        }, 0);
    };
    $(window).on('scroll', scrolling);
})();
```